# How and why does case insensitive XSS work, given that JavaScript is case sensitive?

Tags: xss, javascript

I found a lot of instances where XSS scripts like the following work:

```
<iMg SrC=x OnErRoR=window.location=123>
```

Given that JavaScript is a case sensitive language, how is the browser able to identify it as JavaScript code and execute it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<iMg SrC=x OnErRoR=window.location=123>
```

The mixed case parts in your example are not the Javascript but the HTML. And HTML is case insensitive

```
<iMg     HTML img tag (i.e. image), case insensitive
SrC      src attribute for HTML img tag, case insensitive
OnErRoR  onerror attribute for HTML img tag, case insensitive

window.location=123  - Javascript, case sensitive
```